# How to cluster equally several rows in excel with 5 columns

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a beginner in Excel VBA and I am trying to equally divide the Agent Name/ID into groups where each member are categorized according to its Crift data whether the agent is a Promoter, Neutral or Detractor. Aside from this, those agent with Crift categorization can be identified whether they have sales or no sales...and last thing, the duration of calls (i.e. Short(less than 10 min), Medium(10-20min) and Long(Above 20min)) that was committed by the agent, is equally divide to each group so that in one group there are short, medium and long calls to be evaluate.

```
Agent Name/ID   Sales/NonSales  Crift (P-N-D)   Call Duration (in min)  Repeats
152325            N                 N           8.00                     Y
152336            Y                 N           12.00                    Y
152040            Y                 P           10.00                    Y
152041            Y                 P           13.00                    Y
152046            N                 D           10.00                    N
152189            N                 N           15.00                    Y
151794            Y                 P           24.00                    N
152052            Y                 P           20.00                    Y
151906            Y                 P           23.50                    N
151909            N                 D           15.67                    Y
151893            N                 N           20.36                    N
152048            Y                 D           21.00                    N
151903            Y                 N           19.00                    N
152044            Y                 P           18.25                    N
152032            N                 P           29.15                    Y
152290            Y                 N           26.00                    N
151740            N                 D           10.00                    Y
168334            N                 D           6.00                     N
200679            Y                 N           8.00                     Y
152037            N                 D           7.56                     Y
152026            Y                 D           8.16                     Y
152055            Y                 P           9.28                     Y
152307            N                 P           4.26                     N
152132            Y                 P           16.64                    N
152004            N                 D           16.16                    Y
152017            Y                 P           25.00                    Y
152021            N                 D           26.00                    Y
151914            N                 P           29.16                    Y
151922            N                 N           24.98                    Y
```

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: If by "equally divide" you mean that you want the same number of records (of varying types) in each group, could you sort your data by Duration within Sales/NonSales within Crift, and then select every nth record (assuming you have n groups)?

Comment: Can you provide a sample output?

Comment: As much as possible equally divided to each group, although it is possible 1 or 2 groups are different..groupings will depend on the number of Evaluators, but for now lets have n evaluator...Actually on the last part of it, I need to randomly select sample from each group given the duration, sales/NonSales/Crift/Repeats

Comment: Example Output: Entries must be unique     
     
                                        Group n     
                   Sales|s                               NonSales  
Short     Medium Long     Short       Medium  Long
Agent ID's    Agent ID's Agent ID's   Agent ID's   Agent ID's  Agent ID's
     
Total…..     
Sample Size…..     
     
Note:  For every columns, Agent ID's (in cell) maybe in color coded according to its Crift and Repeats (maybe a combination of 6 colors, like red for Promoter-Yes, Blue for Promoted-No, etc.)

Comment: Even though you are a beginner, could you show us what code you have tried so far. You've probably already read that this site isn't a code-writing service, but we'd happily assist you with anything you've written already.

Comment: Here are my initial codes

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Type Records
Dimension() As Double
Distance() As Double
Cluster As Integer

End Type

Dim Table As Range
Dim Record() As Records
Dim Centroid() As Records

Sub Run()

If Not Grouping Then
    Call MsgBox("Error: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Clustering Error")
 End If

End Sub

Function Grouping() As Boolean
Dim Site As String

Site = Application.InputBox("VXI Site")
Worksheets("Data Base").Activate
Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Value = Site
Cells(2, 1).Font.Bold = True
Cells(2, 2).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

Dim numClusters As Integer
numClusters = Application.InputBox("Specify Number of QA Evaluator", "Grouping", Type:=1)
ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Value = numClusters
Cells(4, 2).Font.Bold = True
Cells(4, 2).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

If Not numClusters > 0 Or numClusters = False Then
    Exit Function        'Cancelled
End If

MsgBox Site & " was an identified site" & " with " & numClusters & " QA Evaluators."

Dim dataSheet, groupSheet As Worksheet
Set groupSheet = Worksheets("Grouping")
Set dataSheet = Worksheets("Data Base")


'dataSheet.Range("A7:A100000").Copy Destination:=dataSheet.Range("g:g")

Dim numAgent As Integer
numAgent = dataSheet.Range("A7:A100000").End(xlDown).Row

Dim startRow As Integer
startRow = 2
Dim startCol As Integer
startCol = 1
Dim agentNumber As Integer


For i = 1 To numClusters
For j = 1 To Round(numAgent / numClusters, 0)
    agentNumber = Int((numAgent - 1 + 1) * Rnd() + 1)
    groupSheet.Cells(startRow, startCol).Value = dataSheet.Cells(agentNumber, 7).Value
    dataSheet.Cells(agentNumber, 7).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    numAgent = numAgent - 1
    startRow = startRow + 1
Next j

If i < 7 Then
    startRow = 2
    startCol = startCol + 1
ElseIf i = 7 Then
    startRow = 14
    startCol = 1
Else
    startRow = 14
    startCol = startCol + 1
End If
Next i


Grouping_Error:
Grouping = (Err.Number = 0)

End Function

Sub SearchForString()

Dim LSearchRow As Integer
Dim LCopyToRow As Integer

On Error GoTo Err_Execute

'Start search in row 7
 LSearchRow = 7

'Start copying data to row 4 in Grouping (row counter variable)
 LCopyToRow = 4

 While Len(Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) < 10

  'If value in column E = "Mail Box", copy entire row to Sheet2
  If Range("E" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "Y" And "N" Then

     'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
     Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
     Selection.Copy

     'Paste row into Sheet2 in next row
     Sheets("Grouping").Select
     Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste

     'Move counter to next row
     LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

     'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
     Sheets("Data Base").Select

  End If

  LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

Wend

'Position on cell A3
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Range("A").Select

 MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

 Exit Sub

 Err_Execute:
 MsgBox "An error occurred."

 End Sub
```